# Print text file with python

Tags: python, kodi

Editing a kodi plugin at the moment and trying to solve to print out a specific txt-file with python.

There is a txt located on another folder containting: build021.7.0

I want to be able to print out the version number.

How can this be done?

Would really appreciate some help!

Thanks!

/Martin

Comment: Is the version number part of the file, the whole file or part of the filename?

Comment: I think `os.listdir` would help your case : https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir

Comment: The file is called version.txt containing < build >build02< / build>
 < version >1.7.0< / version >

Comment: Have to say that I don't understand a thing about python. Would really like you guys who knows to print out a code for me if that's possible?

Comment: And I would really want a million dollars but Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask for either that or for someone else to do the work for you!